# In yacc, how to put a definition into a variable?

Tags: parsing, yacc

In my yacc file I have the following code:

```
fun_declaration : type_specifier ID '(' params ')' 
                  {$2->type = "function";
                   $2->args = params; }

params : param_list | VOID ;
```

Do you see what I'm trying to do?

args is a string.  I'm trying to put the function parameters into this string.  How to do that?

Comment: Has it occurred to you to look at the documentation for yacc? These questions you ask are almost unbelievable to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have 'params' return the string you want in $$, much like ID is returning a pointer to some struct with 'type' and 'args' fields.  This means you'll need a %type declaration for it saying which element of the %union to use.

There are lots of books and online tutorials for how to use yacc like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just refer to with `$n` it as you would refer to any semantic value component in the rule. Something like this:

```
 $2->args = strdup($4);
```

Comment: When I try that I get the error "`fun_declaration' has no declared type."